# Can I call a backend service instead of an instance in GCP?

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, backend

I have a few compute engine instances in a Google Cloud Platform project.
One is my API "api-inst" and is inside a backend-service: api-service
One is my db  2db-inst" and is inside a backend-service: db-service

They are both callable through the load balancer.
Sometimes the API needs to call the DB.

I would like these calls to be dealt with internally for performance purpose. 
But I might have several db instances inside my db-service, therefore I cannot make the call through the internal IP

Therefore I wonder if there is a way to make my call directly to the backend service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the request directly to backend service is not possible. Instead you might want to include an [internal Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/internal/) in your architecture.